# How to count letters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is working code to check the word count, but I need to count by letters:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {
        var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;

           $('#display_count').text(words);
            $('#word_left').text(10-words);


 if(words > 10) {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
           var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 10).join(" ");
            $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
    }else{
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
    }

    });
 });
```

Comment: This appears to be a javascript question. You have also tagged it with php.

Comment: Have you tried `this.value.length`? or `this.value.replace(/ /g,"").length`

Comment: Check this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/67XDq/15/)

Answer (score 9):

One of the way to solve this problem:

```
let str = 'how to count letters in javascript.'
let letterCount = str.replace(/\s+/g, '').length;

console.log(letterCount) //30
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//using javascript
var a = document.getElementById("inp");
a.addEventListener("keyup",function(){
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "Count :" + " "+ a.value.length;
})
```

```html
<input type="text"  id="inp">
<br>
<span id="count">Count :</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This counts by letter as you requested.
Use `.length` count letter in a variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#word_count").on('keyup', function(e) {
        var words = this.value.length;//I changed this
        //var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
           $('#display_count').text(words);
            $('#word_left').text(10-words);


 if(words > 10) {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
           var trimmed = $(this).val().split(" ").join("");
            $(this).val(trimmed);
    }else{
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
    }

    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="word_count"><br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p id="dispay_count"></p>

<p id="word_left"></p>
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation here

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the string to an array and filter all spaces out.

```js
var text = 'Hello world! And all the people';
var length = text.split( '' ).filter( c => c != ' ' ).length;
console.log( length );
```

Or you could replace all spaces with an empty string and then count the string length:

```js
var text = 'Hello world! And all the people';
var length = text.replace( /\s/g, '' ).length
console.log( length );
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to replace spaces `.replace(/ /g,"")` rather than splitting the string`.split()` to filter it `.filter()`

Comment: Yes, there are multiple paths to achieve this. But I'm wondering what would be more performant

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to omit the non-word characters and then calculate length after joining them.

```js
let str = 'how to count letters in javascript.'
let letterCount = str.split(/\W/).join('').length

console.log(letterCount)
```